# Как возвращать результат из Redis по ключу используя пагинацию?

Tags: c#, redis

Используя Redis я могу возвращать значения из ключа используя пагинацию? В инете пишут, что можно использовать SetScan

var result = database.SetScan(presentationsKey,pageSize: 10,cursor: 0).ToArray();

Но у меня всё равно подтягиваются все записи

Пока я подтягиваю все записи, но мне нужно их разбить по пагинации

```
    public long[] GetPresentationIds()
    {
        IDatabase database = _connectionMultiplexer.GetDatabase();

        string presentationsKey = GetPresentationsKey();

        //Пока подтягиваются все элементы из ключа, нужно добавить пагинацию
        string[] scanResult = database.SetScan(presentationsKey)
            .Select(x => (string) x).ToArray();

        return Array.ConvertAll(scanResult,
            long.Parse);
    }
```